# How to style a React component with changes in only one direction

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a React component which opens up a popup on a button click. So the popup has a Scrollbar and there is another component below the popup which contains the confirmation button and cancel button. Currently the popup's scrollbar is overlapping the other component as shown below:

[image: popup's scrollbar]

The code for the screen is pasted below:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

  const Wrapper = styled.div`
        width: 90vw;
        height: 90vh;
    `;

    const Content = styled.div`
        height: fit-content;
        padding-bottom: 150px;
    `;



 return (
        <Wrapper>
            <Content>{popupToDisplay()}</Content>
        </Wrapper>
    );
```

The popupToDisplay() function displays a popup depending on the result of a switch case.

So, now I am trying to move the Scrollbar above the purple line as shown in the image. I am able to reduce the size of the Popup by decreasing the **'height'** property of the Wrapper component as shown below:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
    width: 90vw;
    height: 40vh;
`;
```

But now the issue while doing so is since the height is getting decreased, the popup is coming down from the top, i.e. there is space at the top as shown below:

[image: screenshot]

I don't want the top of the popup to move down, only the bottom of the popup should move up. I also tried giving **'margin-bottom'** property to the Wrappper constant, but its still not working. Can someone please help me with this.